# replication from mongodb atlas to on premise?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, nosql

I want this functionality - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/ - except that my primary will be a node in mongodb atlas on awas and some of my secondaries will also be in atlas aws, but I will also have some secondaries on premise running in a kubernetes cluster.

Basically I want one read/write mongodb master and many read-only secondaries, some secondaries in public cloud and some secondaries on premise. So I am looking for using mongodb for that - if mongodb cant do that, can you please recommend some other database that might be able to do it ? I would prefer a nosql db, but if nothing can do it then a sql db is also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't currently have an Atlas cluster with a node outside of Atlas however it should be possible to maintain a mirror of your main cluster using a [ChangeStream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) to mirror all writes to one or more on premise nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But if I use regular non-Atlas mongodb installation in the cloud, then I guess I can have an on-premise mongodb as a read-only mirror ?

Comment: yes, in that case you could also have a read-only replica precluding the need for change streams.